# Reformatting date value in content-script for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, date, split, createelement

I have the following function that creates a table and inserts the date & price into rows within the table:

```
function createTable({ data, propertyId }) {
  const table = createElement({
    tag: 'table',
    id: `p-${propertyId}`,
    border: '1',
  });

  const tableHeader = createElement({
    tag: 'caption',
    innerText: 'Table title',
  });

  const tableBody = createElement({
    tag: 'tbody',
  });

  //order dates so that most recent is displayed last
  data
    .sort((prev, current) => {
      const prevDate = prev['date_created'].replace('/', '-').replace('/', '-');
      const currentDate = current['date_created']
        .replace('/', '-')
        .replace('/', '-');
      return new Date(prevDate) - new Date(currentDate);
    })
    .forEach((item) => {
      const row = createElement({
        tag: 'tr',
      });

      const date = createElement({
        tag: 'td',
        innerHTML: item.date_created,
      });

      const price = createElement({
        tag: 'td',
        innerHTML: item.price,
      });

      row.append(date, price);
      tableBody.append(row);
    });

  table.append(tableHeader, tableBody);
  return table;
}
```

The date format is currently: YYYY/MM/DD and I'd like it to be DD/MM/YYYY. I have the below function that reformats the date as I'd like it to, but I've been struggling to implement into my code, as I can't call the function in `innerHtml` where the date is being populated (`item_date_created`). Can anyone please advise?

```
function reformatDate(dateStr) {
  var dArr = dateStr.split('-'); // ex input: "2010-01-18"
  return dArr[2] + '/' + dArr[1] + '/' + dArr[0].substring(2); //ex output: "18/01/10"
}
```

For example, adding:

```
let reformattedDate = reformatDate(item.date_created);
```

below for the forEach gives the following output:
`undefined/undefined/22/11/06`

Comment: If you are passing in the string that you say you're passing, then your output should be as expected. Since you're getting undefined in the output values, your input string is not what the function is expecting. Could you print out the value for `dateStr` when this error happens?

Comment: I think the issue might be in the reformatDate function - as if I log out dateStr in my function (before executing the split etc - it logs "2022/10/13", for example. Its only after completing the function and then logging again - it returns: "undefined/undefined/22/11/03"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue like so:

```
    .forEach((item) => {
      let reformattedDate = reformatDate(item.date_created);
      const row = createElement({
        tag: 'tr',
      });

      const date = createElement({
        tag: 'td',
        innerHTML: reformattedDate,
      });

      const price = createElement({
        tag: 'td',
        innerHTML: item.price,
        className: 'pp-price',
      });

      row.append(date, price);
      tableBody.append(row);
    });
```

```
function reformatDate(dateStr) {
  const [year, month, day] = dateStr.split('/');
  const result = [day, month, year].join('/');
  return result;
}
```